# how to determine the Remaining useful life of lithium battery given charging discharging voltage, load, temperature of different cycles?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, capacity

given 3 datas

1st-dataset contains charging details with fields:Voltage_measured,Current_measured,Temperature_measured,Current_charge,Voltage_charge,Time.

2nd-dataset contains discharging details with fields:Voltage_measured,Current_measured,Temperature_measured,Current_charge,Voltage_charge,Time,Capacity.

3rd-dataset contains impedance details with fields:Sense_current,Battery_current,Current_ratio,Battery_impedance,Rectified_impedance,Re,Rct.

From this which dataset and which particular fields are necessary to predict 1.SOH(state of health) 2.RUL (remaining useful life/capacity) of battery

I am totally new to this domain. sorry if this doesn't make sense. The dataset is from battery dataset. https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/dash/groups/pcoe/prognostic-data-repository/

Comment: This is an incredibly complicated topic, and one you could dedicate several Ph.D. dissertations to. I don't think you'll get a satisfactory answer here.

Comment: Can you analyze this data for Ah capacity changes and charging efficiency and ESR changes to compare the results? This takes a bit of work using pivot tables for each variable to determine the sensitivity to Ah vs C rate, temp, Vcutoff CV limit etc. But the fact is accelerating (alpha) variables for reduction in MTBF determine the sensitivity to each variable and presently CC,CV Rates are optimized for short term capacity and if reduced to 50% capacity you can 10x more charge cycles by going between 40 to 90% SOC only and keep the battery temp rise at minimal

Comment: the readme files says " Impedance measurement was carried out through an electrochemical impedance spectroscopy (EIS) frequency sweep from 0.1Hz to 5kHz. Repeated charge and discharge cycles result in accelerated aging of the batteries while impedance measurements provide insight into the internal battery parameters that change as aging progresses. The experiments were stopped when the batteries reached end-of-life (EOL) criteria, which was a 30% fade in rated capacity (from 2Ahr to 1.4Ahr)

Comment: . This dataset can be used for the prediction of both remaining charge (for a given discharge cycle) and remaining useful life (RUL).

Comment: This can reasonably be accomplished with a coulomb counter. There are ICs on the market that will do most of this for you.